Mechanism reaction of 2-heptenal in presence of a base
I just have a dull moment about the reaction mechanism of the 2-heptenal to the dienol phosphate. To me it looks like deprotonation occurs on the C-4 which is certainly no the most acidic proton and from there the move of the double bond on C-2 starts. Would appreciate any valuable input.
Thanks

The only resonable mechansism with regards to resonance would be the following:


Which proton of the enal do you think is the most acidic then? Seems to me that deprotonation there followed by resonance and then attack of the O- on the chlorophosphate explains this well enough.

Thanks for your answer. I edited the original post with the mechanism that I think only makes sense but not from the view with acidity of protons

@Steven: The reaction path is reversible and it is possible to make both $\ce{C-P}$ and $\ce{O-P}$ bonds. Since $\ce{O-P}$ bond is very strong compared to that of $\ce{C-P}$ bond, your final product (thermodynamic) is the one given.

That didn't answer the question but I think I found the solution myself. Under the given reaction conditions, the reaction is under thermodynamic control and deprotonation  of the γ-proton favoured.

@Steven It certainly makes sense as far as acidity of protons is concerned. I guess you thought alpha should be more acidic (and should say so!) but there's double bond it there! Essentially the removed proton is alpha, just from "enone group"
